# How to change the line value according to the level of hierarchy in my chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a stacked column chart with column values and line values. 
In my X axis I have 2 fields (Departments and Subdepartments).

The column values contain the the total sales and the line value contains the objetive.

The problem is that when I drill down to subdepartments the chart still shows the line value from Departments. I need to change the line value according the level of my hierarchy.

This is my chart for Departments:

[image: 1st pic]

This is my chart by subdepartments and as you can see the line value remains, I need the line value disappear for this chart level:

[image: 2nd pic]

Comment: do you want to hide line on subdepartments or line is not plotting correctly on subdepartments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the right measure. For example:

You have a stacked line chart. On the first level you have Months and on the second level (drilldown level) you have weeks. You can use the following measure:

```
DisplayOnlyMonths = IF(Distinctcount(YourTableName[Date].[Month]) > 1; 
                       Blank(); 
                       Sum(YourTableName[YourValue]
                       )
```

This line will only be shown when you are at the month level. When you drill down to weeks it will disappear.